# What do you call this type of notification(?) and is it available in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, material-design

What do you call this type of notification?
[image]

I looked in the Android Docs, Material.io, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Use flutter_local_notifications https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications to show a notification. For FCM use firebase_messaging

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Comment: I've used notifications, but this is something different.

Comment: can you explain bit more what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a toast notification. Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_styled_toast